# Minus sign in Table

Tags: tables

What is the correct way of doing a minus sign in a LaTeX Table?  The minus sign I'm doing seems much longer than the minus sign in math mode.

Comment: Surround the entire number with $$. Example $-5$ that puts it in math mode.  If that does not work, please provide a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that shows the problem.

Comment: no, it is the other way round: the minus in math mode is longer than the hyphen character

Comment: @Herbert: I suspect the OP is using `---` and it is too long.

Comment: @PeterGrill: Maybe, but without an example we can only guess ...

Answer (score 12):

A minus sign in a table should be typeset in math mode to get the proper size and spacing:

[image]

The `amsmath` package is only required for the line where `\text` is used.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% only needed for last case where \text{} is used
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular} { l c }
    minus sign outside math mode (incorrect) & -5 \\
    minus sign inside math mode  & $-5$\\
    minus sign but not for a number  & $-$foo\\
    minus sign but not for a number  & $-\text{foo}$
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What about \noindent\llap{-}5?

Comment: @JG: This would still have incorrect spacing between the operator and the operand. Moreover, if used with other surrounding text, the spacing would be wrong.

Comment: Then what does that do?  And, what is all of this foo stuff?  I see lots of foo talk out there in latex land.

Comment: @JG: I just used `foo` to indicate random text.  It not a specific command.

Comment: I still don't understand the llap.  Why did I read to do that?

Comment: @JG: I think that you misunderstood what you read. You should post a separate question as the purpose of `\llap` is not to produce a minus sign.